# How to maintain the lb dns in eks

Tags: kubernetes, aws-api-gateway, amazon-eks, aws-nlb

I have connected AWS API Gateway to NLB in my eks using VPC Links. I have around 3 microservices which are served with 3 NLBs(private to VPC) respectively.

Due to cost reduction I am planning to deploy the microservices only during for 8 hrs during the day. I am planning to do this via a jenkins job

I have an issue of creating an attaching the api gateway vpc links manually.
**Is there any method where we can uninstall and reinstall the eks deployment but get the same dns for nlb?**

or **Do we have any method to schedule deployment to sleep for specified time?**

Comment: You don't have to delete your service along with your deployment. Your service can stay while your deployment doesn't exist. Load balancer will not work, it will give 5xx error because of non-existent backend but when you deploy your app back, it will work.

Comment: I had the same idea, but I deploy with helm chart which includes the deployment and service as well. To delete deployment alone, I need to store the deployment file to redeploy it. Is there any other way ?